# Mistake in (Baby) Do Carmo? Elementary topology of surfaces.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

If you have the book, it's proposition 2 of section 5.3. If not, the proposition reads:

*Given any two points p and q* $\in$ *a regular, connected surface S, there exists a parameterized piecewise differentiable curve joining p to q.*

Now the proof begins as follows:

Since S is connected, there exists a continuous curve $\alpha:[a,b] \rightarrow S$ with $\alpha(a)=p$ and $\alpha (b)=q$. This is the part I struggle with. It appears to me that Do Carmo is asserting that the surface is in fact path connected, which is not true, since connected does not imply path connected in general subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ where all the surfaces live. I thought that maybe something in regularity might solve this problem, but here is the definition of regularity.

A surface is regular if for every point $p$ in the surface, there is a neighborhood $V$ in $\mathbb R^3$ and a map $x:U\rightarrow V \cap S$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ so that $x$ is onto so that the following are satisfied:

1) $x$ is differentiable.

2) $x$ has a continuous inverse (that is to say, is a homeomorphism)

3) $x$ has a one-to-one differential.

I don't see why this must get me path connectedness. I feel like the condition that $U$ is any open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ allows me to pick a sufficiently ugly set and define a surface as a function from that open set to $\mathbb R^3$ which will satisfy these properties, but I have not yet found an example.

So in short the question is, what is the justification for saying *connectedness* $\implies$ *path-connectedness* in this proof?

Comment: +1 for asking a question which includes context and your thoughts on it.

Comment: A lot of times (like this time!) writing out my thoughts instead of just thinking in my head gives me the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All manifolds are locally path-connected by the definition of manifold charts. If a topological space is connected and locally path-connected, it is path-connected.

Answer (score 2):

This is a silly question, in hindsight. I was struggling with this for a while and it just hit me after submitting this that connected open subsets of $R^n$ are in fact path-connected if they are compact (and according to the comments, even if they aren't, the idea is the same). You can form straight lines in ever $\epsilon$ ball connecting any two points, and by compactness, there are only finitely many $\epsilon$ balls. Joining these paths forms a single continuous curve.

Comment: You do not actually need compactness here - connected + locally path-connected $\implies$ path-connected is true for any space, not just compact ones.

Comment: I see. So far we have only considered compact surfaces, but I can see how it holds in general. We should do something similar, but by considering the points which can be connected via path and those that can't, and then showing that the latter is empty with a similar kind of path joining argument.... partition the space into the set of points which can and can't be connected, and reach a contradiction against what connectedness means.

Comment: Excuse my rambling, I will try to make this argument rigorous and perhaps post another question.

Comment: That's precisely the right idea. You just need to show that equivalence classes (say $a \sim b$ if $a$ and $b$ can be connected by a path) are open.

Answer (score 1):

Connected plus locally path connected implies path connected.

Comment: yeah that just hit me after trying to figure it out for a little while. I answered my own question as well because I thought it might be worth it in case anyone else is confused, but thanks!

Comment: understood. Funny how writing up a question clearly can make it far easier to answer for yourself, isn't it?

Comment: For every question I actually submit here, I write up at least two more and answer them in the process. I love this place.